# Error al instalar PyHook3 1.6.1

Tags: python-3.x, pip

Estaba haciendo un keylogger y había hecho un import pyHook, lo cual me decía que no exisitía he estado investigando por internet como instalarla y tal , y he encontrado en la siguiente pagina los archivos de instalación https://pypi.org/project/PyHook3/#modal-close, he probado a instalarlo de la siguiente manera
*pip install PyHook3-1.6.1-cp35-win32.whl* , pero me da el siguiente error *ERROR: PyHook3-1.6.1-cp27-win32.whl is not a valid wheel filename.*

agradezco vuestra ayuda con este tema , muchas gracias.

He probado a hacer pip install pyHook3 y me sale lo siguiente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

en la misma página qi indicas exolican el comando a utilizar para instalar PyHook

```
pip install PyHook3
```

Prueba de esa manera y cuenta nos como te va

Comment: vale ya lo puse en unas imagenes lo q me sale

Comment: Disculpa la demora, recién me llegó la notificacion.

El error dice command swig.exe failde: None

Aparentemente es un error de dependencias, o sea faltaría instalarlas
Según https://github.com/gggfreak2003/PyHook3 dice que requiere:

- Windows 2000 o superior
- Python 3.2 o superior
- PyWin32 library (https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/)
y finalmente menciona al swig: 
> If you want to build PyHook3 from source code, then you additionally need - MinGW (with gcc-core, gcc-g++, binutils, runtime, utils, w32api) (http://www.mingw.org/) - SWIG (http://www.swig.org/)